# How to stop webpack using caching/hashing output files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've been bundling my nodejs web app with webpack using a template.

The webpack config in this had:

```
 output: {
   filename: `[name].js?v=[${project.build.hashType}]`,
   path: project.paths.public(),
   publicPath: APP_PUBLIC_PATH },
```

The issue is our new CDN/proxy setup doesn't work with these query strings appended - it causes a mismatch with the MIME type in the headers and wont render anything in the browser.

I've done the obvious and removed the query string `?v=[${project.build.hashType}]`. But for some reason the assets are still appended with the same hash.

[image]

The command I'm running to build is

`$ cross-env NODE_ENV=production DEBUG=app:* webpack --bail --config config/webpack.config.js`

Does webpack cache these hashes? I cannot find them in the file structure. I'm quite inexperienced with webpack so any guidance will be highly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...

There was a webpack middleware using a prewritten buildstats file that contained the file versions, so my changes to the output files were never reached.